# Access master page control not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I work with a master page in which there is one `HyperLink`. I set that `HyperLink` `NavigateUrl` form (master page's) child page.

for that i use this code in child page.

```
HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)this.Master.FindControl("linkviewmysite");
hl.NavigateUrl = "../" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
Response.Redirect("Siteadmindata.aspx", false);
```

here `linkviewmysite` is the id of master page's `HyperLink`.

now problem is when i set `NavigateUrl` it's not work.

But when is remove this line (`Response.Redirect("Siteadmindata.aspx", false);`) from code than navigateurl set and HyperLink is work fine for me.

so now what should i do for it `with Response.Redirect`.

Comment: i didn't get your problem

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo sorry about my english. please tell me in which part you can't get. i can try to change it .

Comment: my question is when does the code snippet that you have provided run in your application?

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo i have one login page name with siteadminlogin.aspx(with same masterpage). now this given code is run when i try to login form siteadminlogin.aspx page.

Comment: so you want to redirect to SiteAdminData.aspx when the user has successfully logged in to your site? What is not working in your code?

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo yes you are right. now problem is when successfully logged  than i set  HyperLink  NavigateUrl according to login name. but it not work on next page(Siteadmindata.aspx).

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo salamat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer

```
HyperLink hl = (HyperLink)this.Master.FindControl("linkviewmysite");
session["user_name"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["username"].ToString();
Response.Redirect("Siteadmindata.aspx", false);
```

now in master page page load

```
if(!postback)
{
if(session["user_name"]!=null)
{
linkviewmysite.navigationurl="../"+session["user_name"].tostring();
}

}
```